# Reinitialising Fragment when closing activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, service, ondestroy

I have an Activity with a fragment, this fragment has a map in it and some markers.
I run a service in the background that changes the position of the markers.

Each Marker has a boolean "isDrawn" and whenever the boolean is set to false the map is updated by adding drawing the marker ( I use LiveData to observe the markers)
Whenever I close the Activity that contains the fragment I call onDestroyView, which sets isDrawn of every marker to false. That way when I open the Activity again, the markers get drawn one more time. All of this works fine.

The problem is this: in the Fragment I can tap on the markers, which opens a view that has a button which opens another Activity, when I close this Activity (With BackButton) and if a marker changed its position (through the service)  when I was in said Activity, I find that there are two of the same marker on the map.

Any idea what I could do? Should I remove the fragment and create it again when I close the activity? is that possible? if so how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try 2 options

1. Try creating a static variable and and store some flag values.
2. check whether the Fragment is visible with the help of isVisible() or getUserVisibleHint()

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the first option?

Comment: as simple you can just increment value of the variable or make bool variable true whenever you click on the fragment to open the new activity which has a button.
and in the function which draws or add the marker check for this static variable data is not got incremented then draw or add marker.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using this method to add a marker to the map.

```
public final Marker addMarker (MarkerOptions options);
```

take one variable of type `Marker` and store the reference of it which is returned by `addMarker (MarkerOptions options);`

like

```
if(marker!=null){
 marker.remove(); //will clear the previous one, it might be null at first.
}  
marker=addMarker(yourOptions);//will add the latest one
```